# Ruby Implicit DB Connection like ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, database, cassandra, datastax-ruby-driver

I'm wondering if there is a way to connect and disconnect to a DB implicitly using Ruby like `ActiveRecord`. I'm working on connecting with Cassandra and the team doesn't want to write the connection lines manually. They just want to give the table name (a.k.a. Column Family) to the class I want to build and move on from there.

I also want to assure that I don't connect and disconnect every time when performing parallel insertions to a table (but disconnect after the whole insertions are finished) since the reconnection process is very expensive and slows down the task.

I couldn't find any solution, and the version that my ex-coworker wrote connects and disconnects after each task like the select statement, and the parallel insert. Any suggestions? A code example of any kind of DB would be very appreciated. Thanks.

**NOTE:**
To clarify, I am using a Cassandra driver. I'm not making an ActiveRecord like ORM for Cassandra, but want to expose APIs where the devs don't have to remember writing connecting and disconnecting lines.

Comment: ActiveRecord is an ORM, it sounds like you just need a database driver like this for [Cassandra](https://github.com/cassandra-rb/cassandra)

Comment: I am using a driver. The team doesn't want deal with driver's API. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: so then you want an ORM like this? https://github.com/cequel/cequel/

Comment: Not really. I have seen that one before. We're working on old Cassandra where it relies on thrift. I just want a general abstract example to connect and disconnect automatically.